# rails i18n, the best way to manage localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html for localization. Looks like that the only solution for updating localization is to update yml files. May be there are some solutions or gems which adds ability to update localization via application. For example we can include some gem and update localization files from our app. Is there some solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a great railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) to manage i18n through Redis.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Globalize 3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3). It stores the translation/localization data in the database. There's also a gem to hook it up with [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize3).

Also, while you're at it, don't miss the [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem mentioned in the guide. It translates Rails itself into many languages, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug for my own product here, but check out http://www.localeapp.com for a solution that works with YAML files out of the box.